# Can BBAR coatings be neglected in refraction problems?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, experimental-technology

I am a total novice to experimental optics problems, so I apologize if this is naive. I am wondering whether I can neglect a BBAR coating when calculating an angle of refraction at near-normal incidence. The optical element in question has a fairly standard index (*i.e.*, around 1.5).

Can I just calculate it as if it had a standard reflection and then set the transmission coefficient to $1$ at the end?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can neglect it. It would be hard to measure the difference it makes.

An anti reflection coating is a very thin layer (about 1 wavelength of light thick) of a dielectric with a different index of refraction from glass. The top and bottom surfaces are parallel. So light bends to a new angle on entering the coating, and bends back to the original angle on exiting. The beam is deflected sideways a little. Very much like passing through a window. Since the coating is so thin, the sideways deflection is about a wavelength of light.

A simple AR coating is usually a single layer of $MgF_2$. Light strikes the top layer and some is reflected. Most of the light passes through to the bottom layer, where some is reflected. You pick a wavelength in the center of the human visual range. The thickness is carefully arranged so one ray of that wavelength travels $1/2$ wavelength farther than the other. The two reflected rays are $180^o$ out of phase. The reflections cancel each other out. Canceling is partial for nearby wavelengths, but the coating does a pretty good job.

You can do better by using multiple layers. Then you can choose two wavelengths and find thicknesses where both cancel. Other wavelengths are very nearly cancelled. So this coating is more expensive, but does a better job over a broad band of wavelengths.